# Joomla Custom Login Module Override

Tags: templates, joomla

I am using a custom template for my Joomla site, and I would like to modify the login module so that the user name box, password box, and button all appear on a single line rather than on two.  After receiving a response from a user on the Joomla forum as in how to go about this, I was told that a template override is the best way to make this transition go smoothly, and that I would have to modify by hand the PHP of the login module.  Is this the best and only way of doing this, or  is there an easier way.  Please see the attached text file containing the code.  Please let me know as soon as possible about this.

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_login
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_users/helpers/route.php';

JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_(htmlspecialchars(JUri::getInstance()->toString()), true, $params->get('usesecure')); ?>" method="post" id="login-form" class="form-inline">
    <?php if ($params->get('pretext')) : ?>
        <div class="pretext">
            <p><?php echo $params->get('pretext'); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="userdata">
        <div id="form-login-username" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <?php if (!$params->get('usetext')) : ?>
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <span class="icon-user hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME') ?>"></span>
                            <label for="modlgn-username" class="element-invisible"><?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME'); ?></label>
                        </span>
                        <input id="modlgn-username" type="text" name="username" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME') ?>" />
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <label for="modlgn-username"><?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME') ?></label>
                    <input id="modlgn-username" type="text" name="username" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_VALUE_USERNAME') ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="form-login-password" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <?php if (!$params->get('usetext')) : ?>
                    <div class="input-prepend">
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <span class="icon-lock hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD') ?>">
                            </span>
                                <label for="modlgn-passwd" class="element-invisible"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD'); ?>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <input id="modlgn-passwd" type="password" name="password" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD') ?>" />
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <label for="modlgn-passwd"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD') ?></label>
                    <input id="modlgn-passwd" type="password" name="password" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_PASSWORD') ?>" />
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php if (count($twofactormethods) > 1): ?>
        <div id="form-login-secretkey" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <?php if (!$params->get('usetext')) : ?>
                    <div class="input-prepend input-append">
                        <span class="add-on">
                            <span class="icon-star hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY'); ?>">
                            </span>
                                <label for="modlgn-secretkey" class="element-invisible"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY'); ?>
                            </label>
                        </span>
                        <input id="modlgn-secretkey" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="secretkey" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY') ?>" />
                        <span class="btn width-auto hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY_HELP'); ?>">
                            <span class="icon-help"></span>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <label for="modlgn-secretkey"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY') ?></label>
                    <input id="modlgn-secretkey" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="secretkey" class="input-small" tabindex="0" size="18" placeholder="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY') ?>" />
                    <span class="btn width-auto hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_SECRETKEY_HELP'); ?>">
                        <span class="icon-help"></span>
                    </span>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if (JPluginHelper::isEnabled('system', 'remember')) : ?>
        <div id="form-login-remember" class="control-group checkbox">
            <label for="modlgn-remember" class="control-label"><?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_REMEMBER_ME') ?></label> <input id="modlgn-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes"/>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div id="form-login-submit" class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" tabindex="0" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo JText::_('JLOGIN') ?></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php
            $usersConfig = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_users'); ?>
            <ul class="unstyled">
            <?php if ($usersConfig->get('allowUserRegistration')) : ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=registration&Itemid=' . UsersHelperRoute::getRegistrationRoute()); ?>">
                    <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_REGISTER'); ?> <span class="icon-arrow-right"></span></a>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=remind&Itemid=' . UsersHelperRoute::getRemindRoute()); ?>">
                    <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_USERNAME'); ?></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=reset&Itemid=' . UsersHelperRoute::getResetRoute()); ?>">
                    <?php echo JText::_('MOD_LOGIN_FORGOT_YOUR_PASSWORD'); ?></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
        <input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.login" />
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo $return; ?>" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php if ($params->get('posttext')) : ?>
        <div class="posttext">
            <p><?php echo $params->get('posttext'); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: The change should be made as a template override. You could float the `.control-group` class but it also depends on the container from the template which could have a set width and not allow the fields to float. I know on the Joomla 3.4 admin login form, you can't float the divs without modifying the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by a template override as suggested, but it can also be done by simply adding a few new style rules to your css. Something like the code below should do it:

```
.userdata .control-group{float:left;}
```

( see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4LbL963t/2) for a working example)